# Apply alternate class on li with hidden li present in the list without using :visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have list of li which have some hidden li also. I am applying css class by using this method

```
function ArrangeAlternateRows() {
    $('#' + firstContainer + ' li, #' + secondContainer + ' li').removeClass('AltRow');

    $('#' + firstContainer + ' li:visible:odd').addClass('AltRow');
    $('#' + secondContainer + ' li:visible:odd').addClass('AltRow');
    $('#' + secondContainer + ' li input[type="text"]').css("width", "100%");
}
```

it works great but in IE-7 ":visible" is not working so i tried to use "not(:hidden)" that also not working.

Is there any alternate to apply css class on li without using ":visible" ?

Comment: I'm wondering why `:visible` is not working for your code in Internet Explorer 7. Are you entering Compatibility View for some reason? Try adding in `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` in your `<head>`.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan i am not working with Compatibility  view

Comment: sure you're not accidentally triggering it? if you're really sure, I can't think of why it won't be working. This buggy behavior seems to have been plugged back in 1.3.2, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a loop to directly assign a class to li.

If you do that you preserve also the compatibility with other browsers (like IE7)

Check : http://jsfiddle.net/b4zhs/2/

Comment: that was what i was working at but in your example how will you handle the hidden li.

Comment: this way -> http://jsfiddle.net/b4zhs/5/
sorry for late, I've seen just now your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
.invisibleItem
{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while making an li visible/invisible add/remove a class, say `visible-li`

```
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li').show().toggleClass("visible-li");
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li').hide().toggleClass("visible-li");
```

So

```
$('#' + firstContainer + ' li.visible-li')  // gives visible li elements inside firstContainer
```